# Simple CUDA Thrust Program Error

Tags: cuda, thrust

I just write an simple CUDA Thrust program, but when I run it. I got this error: thrust::system::system_error at position 0x0037f99c .

Can someone help me to figure out why this happen?

```
#include<thrust\host_vector.h>
#include<thrust\device_vector.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace thrust;
int main()
{

    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(3);
    h_vec[0]=1;h_vec[1]=2;h_vec[2]=3;
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec(3) ;
    d_vec= h_vec;
    int h_sum = thrust::reduce(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end());
    int d_sum = thrust::reduce(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably you're not generating the right kind of code for your gpu's architecture. [Catch the `system_error` and print out its `.what()` message to find out what the error is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14051069/722294).

Comment: I was able to successfully compile and run your code. Please check the suggestion given by JaredHoberock in above.

Comment: I use CUDA Wizard to generate the project. I think the generation of code have no problem. The system error is generate by "int d_sum = thrust::reduce(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end());" The error information is:synchronize: launch_closure_by_values:unspecified launch failure. BTW, while compile the program, I receive a lot warning like: Cannot tell what pointer points to, assuming global memory space. I use memory-check to check the program. It crashed. My GPU is Quadro K2000,CPU is Xeon E5. What's wrong? When I use CUSP library. It also crash when generating sparse matrix. --@Jared Hoberock

Comment: Oh the problem solved. As you suggested, I change the kind of device code generation mode to "compute_20,sm_20".  It works. Thank you very much @Jared Hoberock

Comment: Does someone want to add this as an answer so we can getbthis off the unanswered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions with Thrust:

- If you are compiling your code with `-G` and having trouble, try compiling without `-G`
- You can [catch the errors that thrust throws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api), to get more information.
- It's always recommended to compile your code for the architecture of the GPU you are using.  So if you are on a cc2.0 GPU, compile with `-arch=sm_20`.  If you are on a cc3.0 GPU, compile with `-arch=sm_30` etc.
- Finally, it's recommended to build a 64-bit project.  On windows you would select a release/x64 project.