# Thrust - sorting member arrays of class object on gpu

Tags: c++, sorting, cuda, thrust

Currently I am working on porting a molecular dynamics simulation program, which was written in plain cpu C++, to Cuda. In short, the program initialises a list of atoms, transfers the control to an object of class `CCalc` which calculates atomic forces, velocities and positions for `100` (or another number of) iterations, and finally returns to draw the atoms on the screen.

My goal is to have all compute-heavy functions in `CCalc` run on the gpu. To prevent having to copy all calculation constants in `CCalc` one by one, I decided to copy the whole class to device memory, pointed to by `this__d`. Since the drawing function is called from the cpu, the atom list needs to be copied between cpu and gpu every `100` iterations and as such is not a member of `CCalc`.

In function `CCalc::refreshCellList()`, I want to rearrange `atoms__d` (the atom list residing in device memory) such that all atoms in the same cell are grouped together. In other words, `atoms__d` needs to be sorted with `cellId` as keys.

As I don't want to waste time implementing my own sorting algorithm, I tried using `thrust::sort_by_key()`. And here's where I got stuck. The function `thrust::sort_by_key()` requires `device_ptr` objects as arguments; however I cannot access `cellId` since I can only cast `this__d` to `device_ptr`, which I can't dereference on the cpu.

Is there a way to do this without having to break down the "class on gpu" structure?

Here is (an excerpt of) my code:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include "device_functions.h"
#include <vector>
#include <thrust\sort.h>
#include <thrust\device_ptr.h>

#define REFRESH_CELL_LISTS 20

struct Atom
{
    float pos[3];
    float vel[3];
    float force[3];
    // others
};

std::vector<Atom> atom;
Atom *atom__d;
int noOfAtoms = 0;

class CCalc;
__global__ void makeCells(CCalc *C, Atom *A);

class CCalc
{
private:
    CCalc *this__d;
public:
    const int nAtoms = noOfAtoms;
    int *cellId;
    const int nCellX = 4, nCellY = 3;
    // many force calculation constants

    CCalc()
    {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&cellId, nAtoms*sizeof(int));

        // some other stuff

        cudaMalloc((void**)&this__d, sizeof(CCalc));
        cudaMemcpy(this__d, this, sizeof(CCalc), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    // destructor

    void relaxStructure(int numOfIterations)
    {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&atom__d, nAtoms*sizeof(Atom));
        cudaMemcpy(atom__d, &atom[0], nAtoms*sizeof(Atom), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        for(int iter = 0; iter < numOfIterations; iter++)
        {
            // stuff
            if(!(iter % REFRESH_CELL_LISTS)) refreshCellLists();
            // calculate forces; update velocities and positions
        }

        cudaMemcpy(&atom[0], atom__d, nAtoms*sizeof(Atom), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaFree(atom__d);
    }

    // functions for force, velocity and position calculation

    void refreshCellLists()
    {
        makeCells<<<(nAtoms + 31) / 32, 32>>>(this__d, atom__d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        // sort atom__d array using cellId as keys;
        // here is where I would like to use thrust::sort_by_key()
    }
};

__global__ void makeCells(CCalc *C, Atom *A)
{
    int index = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(index < C->nAtoms)
    {
        // determine cell x, y based on position
        // for now let's use an arbitrary mapping to obtain x, y
        int X = (index * index) % C->nCellX;
        int Y = (index * index) % C->nCellY;

        C->cellId[index] = X + Y * C->nCellX;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    noOfAtoms = 1000; // normally defined by input file
    atom.resize(noOfAtoms);

    // initialise atom positions, velocities and forces

    CCalc calcObject;

    while(true) // as long as we need
    {
        // draw atoms on screen
        calcObject.relaxStructure(100);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I may not be fully understanding the issue.  But after an initial read of your  question, I was able to add `#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>` to the top of your code, and `thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device, cellId, cellId+nAtoms, atom__d);` at the point where you desire to do the sort, and the code compiled correctly (and ran without error) for me.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/4r4RR7J9) is a fully worked example.

Comment: This code compiles fine for me as well, but throws an exception at the call to `thrust::sort_by_key`. After showing the error message _"Unhandled exception at 0x759DC42D in Simulation.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: thrust::system::system_error at memory location 0x0055F9DC"_ it breaks at line 47 in file C:\...\CUDA\v7.5\include\thrust\system\cuda\detail\trivial_copy.inl. By the way, I'm using Visual studio 2013. Do you perhaps have any idea what could cause this issue, or how I could go about finding it out?

Comment: what GPU are you running on, and have you set the compilation architecture to match that GPU?

Comment: The program runs on a GeForce GTX960. I'm using compute_52, sm_52 for code generation.

Comment: are you building a debug project or a win32 project?  If so, switch to building a release, x64 project.

Comment: Yes, that did it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In other words, atoms__d needs to be sorted with cellId as keys.

It should be possible to do that, at your indicated point in the `refreshCellLists` method.  For simplicity, I have chosen to use the raw device pointers directly (although we could easily wrap these raw device pointers in `thrust::device_ptr` also) combined with the `thrust::device` execution policy.  Here is a worked example:

```
$ cat t1156.cu
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>

#define REFRESH_CELL_LISTS 20

struct Atom
{
    float pos[3];
    float vel[3];
    float force[3];
    // others
};

std::vector<Atom> atom;
Atom *atom__d;
int noOfAtoms = 0;

class CCalc;
__global__ void makeCells(CCalc *C, Atom *A);

class CCalc
{
private:
    CCalc *this__d;
public:
    const int nAtoms = noOfAtoms;
    int *cellId;
    const int nCellX = 4, nCellY = 3;
    // many force calculation constants

    CCalc()
    {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&cellId, nAtoms*sizeof(int));

        // some other stuff

        cudaMalloc((void**)&this__d, sizeof(CCalc));
        cudaMemcpy(this__d, this, sizeof(CCalc), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    }

    // destructor

    void relaxStructure(int numOfIterations)
    {
        cudaMalloc((void**)&atom__d, nAtoms*sizeof(Atom));
        cudaMemcpy(atom__d, &atom[0], nAtoms*sizeof(Atom), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        for(int iter = 0; iter < numOfIterations; iter++)
        {
            // stuff
            if(!(iter % REFRESH_CELL_LISTS)) refreshCellLists();
            // calculate forces; update velocities and positions
        }

        cudaMemcpy(&atom[0], atom__d, nAtoms*sizeof(Atom), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaFree(atom__d);
    }

    // functions for force, velocity and position calculation

    void refreshCellLists()
    {
        makeCells<<<(nAtoms + 31) / 32, 32>>>(this__d, atom__d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        // sort atom__d array using cellId as keys;
        thrust::sort_by_key(thrust::device, cellId, cellId+nAtoms, atom__d);
    }
};

__global__ void makeCells(CCalc *C, Atom *A)
{
    int index = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(index < C->nAtoms)
    {
        // determine cell x, y based on position
        // for now let's use an arbitrary mapping to obtain x, y
        int X = (index * index) % C->nCellX;
        int Y = (index * index) % C->nCellY;

        C->cellId[index] = X + Y * C->nCellX;
    }
}

int main()
{
    cudaSetDevice(0);

    noOfAtoms = 1000; // normally defined by input file
    atom.resize(noOfAtoms);

    // initialise atom positions, velocities and forces

    CCalc calcObject;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) // as long as we need
    {
        // draw atoms on screen
        calcObject.relaxStructure(100);
    }
}
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -o t1156 t1156.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1156
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

When building thrust codes, especially on windows, I usually make a set of recommendations as summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20414151/simple-cuda-thrust-program-error/20508138#20508138).